# Swagger with Resteasty 3 + Jetty 9.2 + JAX-RS 3

Tags: jetty, jax-rs, resteasy, swagger

I am trying to [configure an existing application](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/commit/bd9dbd1afec4f1fb14ebe423379b5fc2fce72962) to use Swagger. This application uses Resteasy 3 and Jetty 9.2 along with JAX-RS 3.

My changes are based on the [explanations given on the Swagger wiki](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5).

I have first added swagger 1.5.0 in my [build.gradle](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/blob/bd9dbd1afec4f1fb14ebe423379b5fc2fce72962/rest/build.gradle#L79) before adding annotations [@Api](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/blob/bd9dbd1afec4f1fb14ebe423379b5fc2fce72962/rest/rest-server/src/main/java/org/ow2/proactive_grid_cloud_portal/scheduler/SchedulerStateRest.java#L112) and [@ApiOperation](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/blob/bd9dbd1afec4f1fb14ebe423379b5fc2fce72962/rest/rest-server/src/main/java/org/ow2/proactive_grid_cloud_portal/scheduler/SchedulerStateRest.java#L166) on a resource named *SchedulerStateRest*.

The next step was to edit my [web.xml](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/blob/bd9dbd1afec4f1fb14ebe423379b5fc2fce72962/rest/rest-server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) in order to [hook up Swagger-Core in my Application](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/blob/bd9dbd1afec4f1fb14ebe423379b5fc2fce72962/rest/rest-server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L23) and [Initialize Swagger using Swagger's Servlet](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/blob/bd9dbd1afec4f1fb14ebe423379b5fc2fce72962/rest/rest-server/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L79).

My issue is that when I launch my application, no resource is found when I browse `/swagger.json` or `/swagger.yaml` from http://localhost:8080. However, I get no error while starting Jetty and existing services are running and available.

I have [enabled Jetty logs](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lpellegr/faa990071065db4c0ee3/raw/db9b874e1eb7ac7746d5e8e91f1c4963fcd487c9/swagger-issue) but I found no information relevant to me (the class in charge to launch Jetty embedded is [JettyStarter](https://github.com/lpellegr/scheduling/blob/swagger/scheduler/scheduler-server/src/main/java/org/ow2/proactive/utils/JettyStarter.java#L213)).

By looking for similar problems, I found people who say that swagger content should be available at /v1/api-docs, so I tried different URLs but I always get a 404 error.

Recently, I found a [gist from ben-manes](https://gist.github.com/ben-manes/af6ab5e857f29f55d990) for configuring swagger with Resteasy 3 + Guice 4. I tried to mimic its configuration and deduce the configuration for web.xml based on Guice-servlet explanations but I end up with the same problem as for the configuration explained above (no resource available are the expected address).

Since there is no error while starting embedded Jetty, I wonder if the issue is not related to a wrong address. Do you know how to list "resources" that are available on a Jetty instance?

I noticed that explanations on Swagger wiki are for Resteasy 2.X. Does it mean that Swagger is not compatible with Resteasy 3.x?

Ideas, suggestions, etc. to debug, solve the issue are welcome ;)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: What happens if you open http://localhost:8080/doc/swagger.json?

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured it out yesterday. I'm going to post a sample application on git hub sometime this week since I can't find an example anywhere

Comment: @mad_fox Hello. I am facing a similar problem. On your github repo you said you had to upgrade RestEasy. How did you come to that conclusion? Thanks

Comment: That github project is specific to Jboss EAP 6.x. Jboss EAP 6.x comes with RestEasy 2.x already installed. To use the RestEasy 3.x jars, you must upgrade the jboss jars. You can follow the steps here http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#upgrading-eap61